# Анимация скрытия элемента

Tags: html, css3, html5, вёрстка, css-animation

Есть 2 блока, каждый по 50% ширины экрана. Задача в том, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку одновременно скрывался правый блок и расширялся левый на 100% ширины экрана, всё с помощью плавной анимации. Повторное нажатие на кнопку - возвращение правого блока и сжатие левого.

В моём случае анимация корректно работает только для левого блока. Правый "скачет" и перескакивает на новую строку, создавая пустое пространство. 
Решить необходимо с помощью свойств `transform, transition` не изменяя текущий js.

Я обнаружил, что если ставить свойство `scaleX` в 0, то анимация ломается, но видимо тут проблема в чем-то ещё.

```js
function Collapse(){
  var base = document.getElementById("base");
   var chat = document.getElementById("chat");
  if(base.classList.contains("base_collapsed")) {
    base.classList.remove("base_collapsed");
    chat.classList.remove("chat_expand");
  }
  else {
    base.classList.add("base_collapsed");
    chat.classList.add("chat_expand");
  }
}
```

```css
#chat,
#base {
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #787fff;
  border: 2px solid #500787;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
}

#knowledge-base {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#base.base_collapsed {
    //position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(0);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#chat.chat_expand {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
    <button onclick="Collapse()" id="btn">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```js
function Collapse() {
  var base = document.getElementById("base");
  var chat = document.getElementById("chat");
  if (base.classList.contains("base_collapsed")) {
    base.classList.remove("base_collapsed");
    chat.classList.remove("chat_expand");
  } else {
    base.classList.add("base_collapsed");
    chat.classList.add("chat_expand");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chat,
#base {
  float: left; /* для примера */
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #787fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#base.base_collapsed {
  width: 0;
  border: none;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#chat.chat_expand {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <button onclick="Collapse()" id="btn">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="base"></div>
```

Comment: Да, float улучшает ситуацию. Но то, что приходится убирать бордер у правого блока - это не очень подходит. И хотелось решение с помощью transform.

Comment: Классно двигается